# Tax implications of being a UK employee of a US company?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, employment, national-insurance

I'm a UK resident entering into employment with a US company. They're not currently registered for PAYE in the UK, nor do they yet have a UK entity, and they would like to pay my salary directly from the US entity.

What are the tax implications for me of such an arrangement, compared to being paid by a UK entity? Is this arrangement against my interests, and should I insist that they establish a UK entity and register for PAYE?

(Alternatively, does such an arrangement in some way reduce the overall tax burden that my employer and I face, perhaps by reducing the total amount of National Insurance contributions we must pay, and should I therefore want it preserved?)

Comment: "should I insist that they establish a UK entity and register for PAYE?" is that in _their_ best interest? Are you in a position to make such a request?

Comment: @DStanley *"is that in their best interest?"* - not a clue; that's probably something for answers here to address. *"Are you in a position to make such a request?"* - I suppose that remains to be seen, but for the sake of this question, let's say that the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 4):

*Note: this answer is not authoritative in the sense that I have no personal experience of this, but have rather just assimilated some web searches into my existing understanding of UK tax law.*

If your employer has no "tax presence" in the UK - it's not got any permanent establishment and isn't trading in the UK through an agency or similar - then the employer isn't liable to operate PAYE and nor is it liable to pay *employer* National Insurance.

However, you are still of course liable for income tax, and also for *employee* National Insurance.

I think your employer can nonetheless volunteer to operate PAYE and NI collection on your behalf. If they do this without establishing a UK entity, then I don't think this makes them liable to employer's NI. So this seems strictly better than setting up a fully UK entity, as they would be taking the work of paying the tax away from you without creating a larger liability for them.

If they don't do it on your behalf, then you need to contact HMRC to set up a ["Direct Payment" scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/when-and-how-an-employee-operates-paye-on-their-employment-income) - in this case I think it would cover both income tax and NI.

If the Direct Payment scheme doesn't cover income tax then you'd need to pay income tax through self-assessment at the end of each tax year, and likely make "payments on account" during each tax year.